# What C# type to use to map MySql's POINT data type in Entity Framework Core?

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to determine what is C#'s type for MySql's POINT type, so I can my model's position property.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the source code for [MySqlConnector .NET on GitHub](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-net/), is [DbGeometry](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.spatial.dbgeometry).

Comment: Though you might be right as I've seen the docs, it's not supported(?) in the core version ...

Comment: No, EF Core does not support spatial types yet. There are a couple of issues opened on GitHub addressing, such as: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/1100